# Указать переменную для конфигурации при сборке php 7 из исходников

Tags: php, ubuntu, bash, sh, php7

Пытаюсь собрать php7 из исходников по [этому туториалу](https://codebeer.ru/ustanovka-php-7-v-debian-8/)

Выполняю последовательно команды:

1. `cd /usr/src`  - перехожу в папку /usr/src
2. `sudo git clone https://github.com/php/php-src.git php-7` - клонирую git репозиторий
3. `cd php-7` - перехожу в каталог с исходниками
4. здесь нужно выполнить команду `./configure $CONFIGURE_STRING`, а в переменную передать значение конфигурации:
   `CONFIGURE_STRING="--prefix=/usr/local/php7
   --enable-fpm
   --enable-mysqlnd
   --enable-mbstring
   --enable-sockets
   --disable-pdo
   --disable-phar
   --with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php7/etc/conf.d
   --with-curl
   --with-gd
   --with-fpm-user=www-data
   --with-fpm-group=www-data
   --with-mysql-sock=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
   --with-mysqli=mysqlnd
   --with-openssl
   --with-zlib
   --without-sqlite3
   --without-pdo-sqlite"`

Вопрос: где должна находиться эта переменная? В отдельном файле? В файле `configure`?

Можно сделать так:
 4. `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php7 --enable-fpm --enable-mysqlnd --enable-mbstring --enable-sockets --disable-pdo --disable-phar --with- onfig-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php7/etc/conf.d --with-curl --with-gd --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data --with-mysql-sock=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-openssl --with-zlib --without-sqlite3 --without-pdo-sqlite`, но тогда я не знаю, как пересобрать конфигурацию с другими модулями, а мне часто хотелось бы это делать.

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: А какой результат у `./buildconf --force`? `buildconf` - исполняемый файл.

Comment: команда выполняется без ошибок.

Comment: да, забыл ее указать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта переменная терминала. Если написать так:

```
VARTEST="Some test"
```

и выполнить

```
echo $VARTEST
```

то выведется

```
Some test
```

Так же и здесь. Вы в переменную терминала записываете строку

```
CONFIGURE_STRING="..."
```

которую потом передаёте исполняемому файлу

```
./configure $CONFIGURE_STRING
```

Comment: т.е. эта переменная сохраняется в оперативной памяти?

Comment: @Razzwan, да, хранится в оперативной памяти.

Comment: спасибо, понял.